# How to set a session attribute after clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, session-variables, setattribute

I have a jsp page with multiple links created inside a loop. All the links go to exactly one another jsp page. In the second jsp page I need to find out which link was clicked in the first jsp page. How can I do that ? Is there any way after clicking a link in the first jsp page I can set an attribute instantly, so that in the second page I can get that attribute to determine which link was clicked ?

Here is my code of the loop with the links -- http://pastebin.com/J3JGu5jD

```
<%  
    System.out.println("Going inside loop");
    for(int i = 0; i < n_row ; i++)
    {
        course_name = dbManager.get_course_name(teachers_course_id_list[i]);
        course_id = teachers_course_id_list[i];
%>
        table = '<tr><td> <a href="MarkDistribution1.jsp?course_id_QSparam             
        ='+"<%=course_id%>"+'">'+ "<%=course_id%>" + ': ' + "<%=course_name%>"+'</td>  
        </a></tr>'
        document.write(table);
<%
    }
%>
```

PS: Another question. I have a string variable link. is this the proper way to assign it to the javascript variable --- javascript_variable = <%=link%> ?

Comment: While you are populating links dynamically add an extra parameter to identify links unique.

Comment: Yeah please make use of Query Strings

Comment: You dont need session for that.

Comment: I didn't understand what did you mean..... @ vinoth

Comment: Please can you show me sample code edited from my code using query string ? @ orion

Comment: I changed the link portion of the loop to this-- http://pastebin.com/1zG0QdYx

Used Query String. But on the second jsp page I tried to access like this -- 
String course_id = request.getParameter("course_id_QSParam");

it shows course_id null..what to do now ?

Comment: post the complete new link with course_id in comment. Are you sure, your link looks like below in browser? `http://hostname/course_id=12` something like that

Comment: It doesn't show like this in the browser !!

Comment: This is the new link shown in the browser -- 
http://localhost:8085/jsp_project/MarkDistribution1.jsp

Comment: can you update your way of generating link in question by edit? I can't check in pastebin.

Comment: Then I guess I am out of luck. It seems complicated to paste code in stackoverflow..

Comment: give 4 spaces for paste block of code. just loop part is enough..

Comment: It seems quotes issue. please check it properly.

Comment: I have been checking it for almost 2 hours...could not find it so posted it here for help..

Comment: pls check my post in answer part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird. I solved the problem by changing the code like this,

```
<%  
    String link;
    System.out.println("Going inside loop");
    for(int i = 0; i < n_row ; i++)
    {
    course_name = dbManager.get_course_name(teachers_course_id_list[i]);
    course_id = teachers_course_id_list[i];
    link = "<tr><td> <a 
    href=\"MarkDistribution1.jsp?course_id_QSParam="+course_id+"\">"+course_id+":
    "+course_name+"</td></a></tr>";
%>
    table = '<%=link%>'
    document.write(table);
<%
    }   
%>
```

Assigned java variable link inside the java script variable table using single quote. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: glad to help. Anyway you can check the code was not nested properly. Check my answer.

Comment: You have added some escapes after course_id. hence it did not show any issues. Anyway mark it as helpful, if you want really make this question complete.

Answer (score 1):

don't use scriptlet please. you could use JSTL foreach tag

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

then use the loop in your jsp, you can use GET method to know which link is clicked

```
<c:foreach items="${yourarray}" var="link">

     <a href="myController?link=1"><c:out value="${link}"/></a>

</c:foreach>
```

and in you controller catch the parameter

```
doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){


   String theLink="";
   if(request.getParameter("link")!=null){
      theLink= request.getParameter("link");
      request.getSession(true).setAttribute("clickedLink",theLink);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what hinders you from using jstl. but the doGet() method should work in your case

Comment: can you please check this out -- http://pastebin.com/1zG0QdYx

on the second jsp page I tried to access like this -- String course_id = request.getParameter("course_id_QSParam"); it shows course_id null . What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of your code is

```
<tr>
    <td> 
        <a href="MarkDistribution1.jsp?course_id_QSparam="+<%=course_id%>'></a>
    </td>  
</tr>
```

The mistake you did was closed the `<td>` before `<a>` tag. You can add the remaining parameters like this.

Comment: Good catch. But I don't know why the code ( Given in the comment below ) ran properly...